# Handling Redirect Uri in Ionic for external API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

So I've built a webapp and am making a corresponding mobile app in Ionic. I'd like to make a progressive web app as it'd make my life easier, but I guess Apple doesn't support this yet.

(p.s.  I am pretty new at this stuff)

So I'm using the id.me api to verify military service, which sends back an access token in the redirect uri in order to make api requests.

There are two ways I can do this, through my server, or through the client.

Here is their webflow 
https://developer.id.me/documentation#oauth-overview

This is where I kind of get lost Ionic....

So to kick off the webflow, I have to send the user to id.me's authorization endpoint, which I would do in the inappbrowser

```
https://api.id.me/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token&scope=SCOPE
```

to which id.me sends back an access token on the redirect...

From there, I can snatch the token, save it to local storage and close out the inAppBrowser. What I don't know is where to set the uri? Is it localhost? When you build Ionic on your platform, is running on a local server?

Would I do something like this?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']).controller('AppCtrl', 

function($rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaInAppBrowser) {
    var callback = 'http://localhost:8100/callback';
    $scope.idAuth = function() {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var options = {
          location: 'yes',
          clearcache: 'no',
          toolbar: 'yes'
        };
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('https://api.id.me/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=callback&response_type=token&scope=SCOPE', '_blank', options)
      });
    };


    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event) {
      //and this function is called, so you do something like
      if(event.url === callback){;
        let token = event.url.match(/\#(?:access_token)\=([\S\s]*?)\&/)[1];
        $window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
      }
    });
```

Now, if that callback uri gets hit, it's going to run that function?

Also, and this is where I'm lost. I get how this would work on a local development, but when you build and put this on a device, does that callback uri still exist? Is Ionic running on a local server on the device itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ionic is listening on http://localhost/[YourCallBackURI]. By default it runs on port 80 on the device unless you changed the configuration otherwise. Other ports are used when you are running in emulator mode.

Comment: Thank you man, I haven't seen that anywhere. I'll drop the port then!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a n00b when it comes to redirects -- I am trying something similar but am unable to get my callback html page to fire.  I'm using Auth0 with a "silent-callback.html" page.  My html is in "src/pages/silent-callback/silent-callback.html" and I have declared it in my app.module.ts.  How should I format the redirect exactly?